# How should I setup a small business network?

Tags: windows, networking, printer, nas, windows-domain

I help at a small architectural firm that has about 8 PCs on a local network. They were setup a long time ago and they were added incrementally so each computer was configured seperately and each has it's own admin account. Because there is no uniformity, things keep breaking, mostly access to printers and the NAS drives.
The network currently consists of a switch to which all computers are connected. There is also a NAS Synology drive with two partitions with seperate credentials for management and data. The printers are connected to the closest computer and they are then shared over that computer's IP.
As we are slowly upgrading from Windows XP to Windows 10, I started looking into solutions on how to manage a small number of computers but I couldn't understand most of it. What are some cost effective solutions to manage a small number of computers? What should I look into? Domains? Active directories? Servers?
Basically, I just don't want people installing their own software and viruses and junk on the computers, and I would like to stop with the hassle of installing drivers and configuring them for each and every computer.
If I made myself unclear please let me know in the comments and I'll expand upon the question, but I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Are you asking about how to manage the user credentials specifically?

Comment: I really don't know any of the terms. As I said in the paragraph before last, I just don't want people chaning things on the computers and I want to make driver installation and access to the NAS easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for local server which will be acting as: DHCP, Active Directory and Domain Controller. With this you can control all devices in your local network and how they interact with each other

Comment: Is this a Windows Server or some other piece of software? Also, do I need Windows Pro or can I use Home on the computers?

Comment: Only Windows Pro (or higher) can act as an Active Directory client, and only Windows Server can act as an Active Directory domain controller. (Though Linux with Samba can as well, and it's cheaper.)

Comment: This could be a casual computer with Windows Server installed on it. I would read windows license but for 99% you will need Pro version because it's used in a company.

Comment: Windows Server seems quite expensive. Can I run the server on Linux and will it be compatible with Windows Pro clients?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing this - both with pros and cons and different levels of expense involved.

What you are looking for is an active directory server.  You can either have a new piece of tin in your office running a microsoft exchange server and configure all the necessary setting on it, or you can use a cloud version like Azure Active Directory.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-administer-group-policy

Using Azure means you don't need to invest in new tin and hefty server licencing - you can link it all with Office 365.

The actual set up and what parameters you need is a complex issue that can't be fully answered here.  I'd suggest either some research on google or get in touch with a local microsoft certified engineer and get them to set it up for you.